# Grails Override reserved work in a controller?

Tags: grails, controller, overriding, reserved-words

I am currently working on a Grails solution and I am looking to pass a URL using WSLite, I basically want to pass a bunch of query params and have them fired off. One of the params I need to have is session.name, I need this exactly like this as a 3rd party system can only read data as "session.WHATEVER". However when i enter the data below it has a problem with the "session." as it appears that session is a reserved word in grails. Is there anyway I can get grails not to pick-up the reserved word and just use session.name? Maybe by some sort of override?

```
def response = client.get(path:'/TestingService', query:[code:testCode, session.name: name])
```

Thanks

Comment: I have now fixed this so now worries :-)

Comment: I will add full details of fix when I can :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes:

```
query:[code:testCode, 'session.name': name]
```